# Grouping data by type and displaying

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'product', with a 'created_at' date, and a 'type' which is a varchar.

Essentially what I want is an output of the COUNT(*) of each product for every day, for all of the product types. I know that there are only 5 different values for 'type', so that would narrow it down a bit with the query I imagine.

Example:

[image]

I have been playing around with this with no success, can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have only four types?

Comment: Yep! I know the specific 'types' as well.

Comment: `SELECT t1.created_at, count(t1.*), count(t2.*), ... FROM product t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN product t2 ON t1.created_at = t2.created_at AND t2.type = 'type2' WHERE t1.type = 'type1' GROUP BY t1.created_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type2_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type3_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type4_count,
created_at
GROUP BY created_at
```

For specific date

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type2_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type3_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type4_count,
created_at
WHERE created_at = '2015-12-21'
GROUP BY created_at
```

With date format

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type2_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type3_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'type4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type4_count,
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%m/%d') AS created_date
GROUP BY created_at
HAVING created_date = '2015/12/21'
```

Comment: This worked great! Forgot to ask one thing: is there a way to cast the created_at to a datetime and still use the query above? I tried this : DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, "%Y%m%d") AS `Date`, 
and then grouping by `date`, but that gave me a mysql syntax error...

Comment: check my edited code, I have added Date format to created_at

Comment: Cool, that did it. Thanks!